# Dragging and dropping cells in Excel causes unwanted shading to be applied

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, drag-and-drop

**When I drag and drop cells, shading sometimes gets applied to the original location of the moved cells. How can I prevent this happening?**

- The shading is often grey but can be any colour. It's possible that the only colours that appear have already been used for shading elsewhere in the worksheet but I have yet to verify this.
- Usually all the 'moved-from' cells get shaded, but sometimes only a subset of them get shaded.
- Neither the moved-from location nor the moved-to location have cell shading
  applied before a drag and drop operation.
- Typically, and perhaps every time shading has appeared, the list I'm working with is filtered when I perform the drag and drop operation.

I haven't been able to replicate this behaviour across other worksheets and workbooks so I think it is only happening in one particular worksheet. That sheet contains a large-ish (40000+ records, 25 columns) dataset in the form of a filtered list.

Screenshot showing unwanted shading on the left and dragged cell contents on the right:
[image: Screenshot showing unwanted shading on the left and dragged cell contents on the right:]

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: Does that shading disappear if you save, close & reopen your file?

Comment: No, it doesn't disappear.